# PyCharm 2018.3.3 reformat code leads to broken literal string

Tags: python, pycharm

It appears that the default settings for automatic reformatting of Python code in PyCharm 2018.3.3 (which I'm using) breaks f-strings, as can be seen in this picture:

[image: Broken f-strings after reformat code]

Is there a setting to fix this? Or is it a legit bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a PyCharm bug indeed, I believe [PY-27615](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27615) covers this case.

Comment: Looks like, yes. Thanks for the link.